# trying Insert data of tables into one temporary table and insert again into same temp table from a different table

Tags: sql, database-migration

trying Insert data of tables into one temporary table adn insert again into same temp table from a different table

Select

sfb.SAP_SHIP_TO,sfb.SAP_SOLD_TO,sfb.INVOICE_DATE,fb.MATERIAL_GROUP,sfb.FUEL_GROUP,sfb.INTERFACE_STATUS,sfb.gross_flag,sfb.gross_qty, sfb.net_qty

```
into 
   #mda_temp_sap_fuel_bdocs
from
  mda_agreement_site sas
join  
  sap_fuel_bdocs sfb 
on
 sas.sap__c = sfb.sap_ship_to
where 

 sfb.Interface_Status = 'SUMMED'/*
```

and

*/

### -------------------------------------------Step2

```
Select  
    sfb.SAP_SHIP_TO,
    sfb.SAP_SOLD_TO,
    sfb.INVOICE_DATE,
    sfb.MATERIAL_GROUP,
    sfb.FUEL_GROUP,
    sfb.INTERFACE_STATUS,
    sfb.gross_flag,
    sfb.gross_qty,
    sfb.net_qty

into #mda_temp_sap_fuel_bdocs
from
  mda_agreement_site sas 
join  
  sap_fuel_bdocs_archive sfb 
on
  sas.sap__c = sfb.sap_ship_to 
where 
 sfb.Interface_Status = 'SUMMED'
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: i am not able to run the query. i have a alternative of creating a temp table and iserting both this tables by union all, but it is taking long time to inset as the data is of high volume. i want a better way to run the query fast